# Does there exist a mapping that maps a non-simple connected domain to a simple connected one? Or inversely

Tags: general-topology

I just suddenly came up with this problem. Since the simple connected domain is topologically invariant, therefore there is no bijection for this problem. But I am wondering if there exists any surjection that is suit for this requirement?

Comment: My recommendation to you is to think more about examples. When you see the two examples that @Ludwik has given, you realize that perhaps your question was too general. After you play around with your examples, you may make up questions for yourself that, being less general, have more interesting answers..

Answer (score 1):

Any constant map $f:S^1\to \{x_0\}$ maps the non-simply connected circle $S^1$ to a simply connected point $\{x_0\}$. Inversely, the circle parametrization $f:[0,1]\to S^1$ such that $f(t)=(cost,sint)$ maps the simply connected interval $[0,1]$ to the non-simply connected circle $S^1$.